# Maximum retries exhausted. Could not install VS Code server on [azure compute instance name]: Cannot communicate with the Jupyter endpoint

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to edit my jupyter notebook which is in Azure ML Workspace. I use the 'edit-in vscode' option, it opens the vs-code or when I try to connect to compute instance directly from vs code,  then I am getting the following error:

```
[Info - 2021-11-08 07:06:06.885] Using commit id "b3318bc0524af3d74034b8bb8a64df0ccf35549a" and quality "stable" for server 

[Error - 2021-11-08 07:06:06.971] Invalid response: 405 Method Not Allowed 

[Error - 2021-11-08 07:06:06.971] Cannot communicate with the Jupyter endpoint. 

[Error - 2021-11-08 07:06:07.981] Maximum retries exhausted. Could not install VS Code server on saksham-dubey: Cannot communicate with the Jupyter endpoint.
```

Earlier it was working fine and I had no issues with vs-code, I was able to edit/run files directly but without changing anything, it started giving me problem.
So far, I have tried uninstalling/removing vscode completely, reinstall it, deleting Azure compute instance and creating a fresh instance but nothing worked, I am still facing the issue.

What is the problem here and how to resolve this?

ps- *saksham-dubey* is my compute instance name, which is a Azure Compute Instance (Nvidia Tesla K80 GPU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix to the problem.
The problem was caused due to some backend error in the 'Azure Machine Learning' vs-code extension.

The issue was caused in the version: 0.6.26
The fix was implemented on the version: 0.6.27

Updating your vs-code extension will make it work.

For any further information you can refer: [Github Link to vscode-tools-for-ai](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/issues)

Also you can open an issue on same Github page, if anything like this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Been dealing with the same issue since Friday, tried pretty much anything to no avail.

Luckily I found a workaround by enabling SSH on a new GPU instance & connecting to the instance through Remote SSH from VS Code.

Will keep posted if I found a solution for the UI access.